# How can I fix unknown npm run build error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have an error when I'm typing "npm run build", however, I made this project 4 month ago and there wasn't error like that, now I need to my website. This is an error, that I'm receiving:

$ npm run build

> honest-trading@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

```
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    throw err;
    ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:748:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:448:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:486:19)
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\react-dev-utils\FileSizeReporter.js:139:29
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\react-dev-utils\FileSizeReporter.js:138:48
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\recursive-readdir\index.js:81:22
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\recursive-readdir\index.js:81:22
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\recursive-readdir\index.js:88:20
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'UNKNOWN'
}

Node.js v18.14.2
```

How to fix it?

I have tried to type "npm start" and got this:

```
rror: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\honesttrading\honest-trading\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],      
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.14.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is either due to the **corrupted files** or **old cache files**.

For the cache problem run the following command:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

As **[@heisenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6164389/heisenberg)** mentioned you can try **removing your package lock and install again.**

Comment: if this doesn't solve your problem, try removing your package lock and install again. usually this might due to corrupt files are hosted in your registry somehow, pointed by package.lock (or vice versa).

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it again. Additionally, I have tried commands such as: "npm cache clear --force" / "npm update" / "npm install --force". It doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

The error may be coming because of your nodejs versions run the command

```
node -v
```

there may be a chance that your nodejs version needs to be downgraded as your project is 4 months old. For this you can use [NVM](https://refine.dev/blog/install-nvm-mac-and-windows/) to achieve multiple node versions.use the following command to use a specific node version.

```
nvm use your_specific_version
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it again. Additionally, I have tried commands such as: "npm cache clear --force" / "npm update" / "npm install --force". It doesn't work anyway

Comment: @RuslanMakhmatov try  Delete the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file, and then reinstall the dependencies. run command 
`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
`npm install`.

Comment: It's starting the localhost now, however I still can't build it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solution was:

1- Delete any corrupted/broken/error-giving files in your project folder. Very probably you have some broken/error-giving files that you have created while developing your app and later forgot to delete.

2- Delete "client" folder and recreate it again "npm run build"